# Newest mosquitto on window 10 isn't running

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, mosquitto

The first time I accost MQTT.
I am installing mosquitto from https://mosquitto.org/download/ to build a simple puslish/subcribe. I used the newest version is 1.5.3 and no warning or error when it completed but nothing was occured when I run mosquitto.exe, it only have a black command prompt. Can anyone help me in this situation?

[image]
Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats it running. If you want to see more, you need to start it with the verbose flag -v

```
$.\mosquitto.exe -v
```

If you installed it in the default location, you can run it like this from the command prompt (just copy and paste):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\mosquitto\mosquitto.exe" -v
```

Also note that if you installed it with the Service option (checked by default), the next time you start your PC, it will already be running, so if you try to start it again by clicking on the icon, the command prompt will appear and then close.

Comment: The first time I working with it, could you guide me in detail?

Comment: @HuuChinhNguyen if you open it with the command prompt, open it with the additional flag -v. Then you can see everything it does